# How to increase the size of Android 6's personal dictionary?

Tags: storage, system, customization, dictionary

When adding new words to the dictionary, old words keep getting forgotten. It feels like I can only add about 1000 words (might be off, but that's the order of magnitude). Words disappear in the order they were added in (FIFO), so often basic and commonly used words are removed. Note that this holds for the personal dictionary, the selected language's dictionary is static and remains. So, I keep adding the same words over and over, and sometimes even in the same message, words can get a red underline when adding other words. It seriously feels like the Nokia 3510's dictionary is the same size as my modern Android (and every other Android I ever had), and I'm not even kidding.

How can I increase the dictionary's size? Or alternatively, how can I make android predict more words than it currently does?

My use case is that I use 2 languages interchangeably within sentences; English and dutch slang + dutch dialect. All words I have added are under 'English' in settings. I have several reasons for not switching dictionary languages mid-sentence, but it's mostly convenience. If I did use the dutch dictionary, I would still have the same problem. While dutch may align with dutch slang for ~85%, only ~5% of the words match with my dutch dialect. So basically I'm trying to fit 2 extra languages within my personal dictionary and it doesn't fit.

Any solution may be far fetched or require rooting, I don't care. This issue has been haunting me since my first Nokia phone. My current phone has the storage space for more than a billion words (60 Gb free space, 15 character words in UTF-8), so surely technology has advanced enough to allow more than a thousand words. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

**Specs:**

- Android 6.0.1
- Cyanogen OS 13.1.2